# Getting the parameters of a data ellipse produced by the car package in R

Tags: r, r-car

I am using the dataEllipse function from the car package in R to get an elliptic confidence region for my data. For example:

```
datapoints_x = c(1,3,5,7,8,6,5,4,9)
datapoints_y = c(3,6,8,9,5,8,7,4,8)
ellipse = dataEllipse(cbind(datapoints_x, datapoints_y), levels=0.95)
```

The output are two vectors x and y corresponding to points that define the ellipse:

```
head(ellipse)
#             x        y
# [1,] 12.79906 10.27685
# [2,] 12.74248 10.84304
# [3,] 12.57358 11.34255
# [4,] 12.29492 11.76781
# [5,] 11.91073 12.11238
# [6,] 11.42684 12.37102
```

But rather than that I am interested in the length of the ellipsis axes and its center. Is there a way to get this without carrying out the PCA by myself?

Comment: It's easier to help you when you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include sample input data and the code you are currently running.

Comment: Provide some code and data, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `?dataEllipse` you read that these functions are mostly plotting functions, not functions designed to give you the fitted ellipse. However reading the source code of `dataEllipse`, it becomes clear that the function used to fit the ellipse is `cov.wt` from the `stats` package. This function should be able to give you the center and covariance matrix used to specify the ellipse location and shape:

```
set.seed(144)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- 3*x + rnorm(1000)
(ell.info <- cov.wt(cbind(x, y)))
# $cov
#          x         y
# x 1.022985  3.142274
# y 3.142274 10.705215
# 
# $center
#           x           y 
# -0.09479274 -0.23889445 
# 
# $n.obs
# [1] 1000
```

The center of the ellipse is now readily available from `ell.info$center`. The directions of the axes are accessible as the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix (columns of `eigen.info$vectors` below).

```
(eigen.info <- eigen(ell.info$cov))
# $values
# [1] 11.63560593  0.09259443
# 
# $vectors
#           [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] 0.2839051 -0.9588524
# [2,] 0.9588524  0.2839051
```

Finally you need to know the length of the axes (I'll give the length from the center to the ellipse, aka the radius on that axis):

```
(lengths <- sqrt(eigen.info$values * 2 * qf(.95, 2, length(x)-1)))
# [1] 8.3620448 0.7459512
```

Now we can get the four endpoints of the axes of the ellipse:

```
ell.info$center + lengths[1] * eigen.info$vectors[,1]
#        x        y 
# 2.279234 7.779072 
ell.info$center - lengths[1] * eigen.info$vectors[,1]
#         x         y 
# -2.468820 -8.256861 
ell.info$center + lengths[2] * eigen.info$vectors[,2]
#           x           y 
# -0.81004983 -0.02711513 
ell.info$center - lengths[2] * eigen.info$vectors[,2]
#          x          y 
#  0.6204643 -0.4506738
```

We can confirm these are accurate from using `dataEllipse`:

```
library(car)
dataEllipse(x, y, levels=0.95)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to find whether or not data points fall within the ellipse?

Comment: @a.powell I believe dataEllipse is just a plotting function. I would encourage you to ask a new question so the whole community sees it.